# node-sass gets stuck when compiling sass

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I'm making a portfolio using HTML, CSS, JS, and SASS.
Whenever I try to compile SASS, it's just stuck.

My script:

```
"compile:scss": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, you can just solve it by using this script instead of your script:

```
"compile-sass": "node-sass --watch sass/main.scss > sass/style.css"
```

I recommend that you do not use the `--watch` flag as it sometimes logs errors to the compiled file instead of the log file.